# How to get all HTML objects with type=number

Tags: javascript, html, tags, html-input

I have a group of inputs; some are number inputs, and others text inputs. I know I can get ALL inputs via

```
x=document.getElementsByTagName('input');
```

But how can I do this to get only inputs with type=number? I need a pure JavaScript solution, NO jQuery or other frameworks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Need to use [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) method.

```
x = document.querySelectorAll('input[type="number"]');
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bb5xoeLe/)

Answer (score 2):

You have a good answer, but for older browsers that don't fully support the selector API, you'd use *getElementsByTagName* then filter on type:

```
var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName('input');

for (var i=0, numbers=[], iLen=inputs.length; i<iLen; i++) {
  if (inputs[i].type == 'number') numbers.push(inputs[i]);
}
```

Or if ES5 support is available:

```
var numbers = Array.prototype.filter.call(document.getElementsByTagName('input'), 
  function(input) {return input.type == 'number'}
);
```

Comment: This is helpful, and I appreciate the answer, but I'm not too worried about older browsers. I'd upvote but not enough rep.

Comment: @Leshy—that's fine, I don't care about votes. Answers are for anyone with a similar problem who comes across your question (and hence the answers). ;-)